# How to add Request Body?

Tags: android, android-volley

How to add the request body to my code like using Postman's body tab. I figure it out only request header. ￼

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String url = "url";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.e("Response : ",response.toString());
                textView.setText("Success!");
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Response error : ",error.toString());
                error.printStackTrace();
                textView.setText("Failed!");
            }
        }) 
        {
            @Override
            public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                headers.put("accept-language","EN");
                headers.put("authorization","<autho>");
                headers.put("requestUId","<requestID>");
                headers.put("resourceOwnerId","<resorceOwnerID>");
                return headers;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
    }
}
```

Ref Postman's head tab :

https://s3.amazonaws.com/postman-static-getpostman-com/postman-docs/58960775.png

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your JSONObject request as below:

```
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();

try {
    jsonBody.put("firstname", "asd");
    jsonBody.put("lastname", "asd");
    jsonBody.put("id", "1");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then the third parameter in the `JsonObjectRequest()` constructor is the request, you are currently passing null. Replace it with `jsonBody`.

**Edit**

You also have to change your HTTP method to POST instead of GET if you want your parameters to be sent in the request body.